# Access Local Lambda variables outside Lambda Method

Tags: java, android, lambda

the application i'm writing uses two separate lambda methods in order to stream data from two different sensors (one lambda for each sensor). Each sensor streams an angle and I need to compute the absolute value between both.

A simplified version:

```
  sensorFusion1.eulerAngles().addRouteAsync(source -> source.stream((data, env) -> {
    //streaming data as a variable
    EulerAngles angle1 = data.value(EulerAngles.class)
    }

    sensorFusion2.eulerAngles().addRouteAsync(source -> source.stream((data, env) -> {
    //streaming data as a variable
    EulerAngles angle2 = data.value(EulerAngles.class)
    }

    // Computations Between angle1 and angle 2 here (placeholder)
       absangle= abs(angle1-angle2);
```

The problem i'm running into is that to my understanding local lambda variables need to be effectively final, and my sensors data is continuously changing. Is there a way that I could access the current value of the sensor in Real-time to perform calculations between both angle variables as they are passed from the sensors?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Create atomic references which will hold your angles

```
AtomicReference<EulerAngles> angle1 = new AtomicReference<>();
AtomicReference<EulerAngles> angle2 = new AtomicReference<>();

sensorFusion1.eulerAngles().addRouteAsync(source -> source.stream((data, env) -> {
    //streaming data as a variable
    angle1.set(data.value(EulerAngles.class));
}

sensorFusion2.eulerAngles().addRouteAsync(source -> source.stream((data, env) -> {
    //streaming data as a variable
    angle2.set(data.value(EulerAngles.class));
}

absangle = abs(angle1 - angle2);
```

Don't forget to check `angle1.get()` and `angle2.get()` to null